# Why the Instance of OracleConnection.Open() throws an error after upgrading the Oracle DB from 11g to 19c?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c

Connection String : USER ID=dt;DATA SOURCE=ABCTOOLQ;STATEMENT CACHE SIZE=10;PASSWORD=***;VALIDATE CONNECTION=True;DECR POOL SIZE=1;MIN POOL SIZE=1;INCR POOL SIZE=1

I am using **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess** from Nuget and **System.Data.OracleClient** in project reference.

---

m-connection.open() - Throws an exception

*exception : {"ORA-01034: ORACLE not available\nORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist\nLinux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory\nAdditional information: 3701\nAdditional information: -749403217"}*

Property of m_connection :

The .ServerVersion create below exception :

[image]

Comment: `ORACLE not available` seems to explain the behaviour....

Comment: 1. I am able to connect the DB through Oracle Developer without any issue. DB is up and runnning. 
2. Checked ORACLE_SID environment variable 
3. Verified the ORACLE_HOME from listener.ora and ORACLE_HOME (With the help of Oracle Team )

Comment: _"I am able to connect the DB through Oracle Developer without any issue."_  Then you are connecting to a different database.  "ORA-01034: ORACLE not available\nORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist" is very definitive.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is an Oracle Home issue. DATASOURCE=ABCTOOLQ will go looking in the tnsnames.ora for a reference, eg

```
ABCTOOLQ=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yourhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = yourservice)
    )
  )
```

If that tnsnames.ora cannot be found because

- it was not copied to new client location (if you upgrade the client as well), or
- the TNS_ADMIN environment or registry setting has been altered, or
- the name of the service was altered during upgrade

then you end trying to connect to a *local* (and non-existent) database called "ABCTOOLQ", and thus the "Hey, that database is not there" error.

Comment: the tnsnames.ora file is placed  at DB server as well as at my client system with correct configuration. Still getting the same issue.